# Arduino Nano ESP32 128x64 pixels OLED display stays black

Tags: arduino, connection, display, arduino-esp32

I recently bought an Arduino Nano ESP32 and a display which is the Masterhawk 0.91 Inch 128x32 OLED display and i tried to load an example with test animations.
It worked perfectly fine until a few days ago. It stopped printing anything at the display and the yellow LED D13 has lightend up.
I double checked the connections already and tried to compile the Code again. Everything seems correctly connected and the Code has no failures. Right Below you can see pictures of my connections.
I appreciate any help.[The connections of the display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i95ZI.jpg) [The connections of the Arduino](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxZzD.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.